# less-middleware isn't producing output css

Tags: node.js, less

I have following folder structures and less files to compile using less-middleware. But its not working. I tried all tutorial that I have found on googling. Anyone plz help.

```
app.use(lessMiddleware(__dirname + '/public/less'));
```

folder structure is -

```
public/app.css (where would like to get the output)
//source folders are.
public/less/layout.less, master.less
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What are you trying to do, compile the .less in css and then serve these css files, or do you want to serve the less files directly?
Wich less middleware are you using?

Comment: var lessMiddleWare = require('less-middleware'); I am trying to compile all the less files into css files. I would very much like to have all less files compiles down to let's say app.css file. Do i need to use express-less or less-middleware would be fine. cheers.

Comment: and what exactly is not working, what is your expected behaviour?

Comment: After running node app.js I was expecting the css folder would contain all less file or more accurately one css with all style from less files. But I am getting nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The package [less-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/less-middleware) **does not** compile less Files to Css Files.

For your problem you should look at [gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp).

Gulp helps you with building your project like compiling less to css and much more.

With gulp you can use the gulp plugin [gulp-less](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-less) wich compiles your less.

```
var less = require('gulp-less');
var path = require('path');     

gulp.task('less', function () {
  return gulp.src('./less/**/*.less')
    .pipe(less({
      paths: [ path.join(__dirname, 'less', 'includes') ]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'));
});
```

Now you just need to run `gulp less` to compile your less.
With gulp you can even watch your less files and compile every time they change.

Comment: Do I need to put this in gulpfile.js?

Comment: Yup. put that into gulpfile.js and run it by `gulp less`

Comment: Also, you may want to add a clean task to remove all the css files beforehand.

Comment: I have tried that. doesn't work. I have tried with @Nick D's snippet but its not working. here is the link --- https://jsfiddle.net/5t7sez19/